# Returning only values that match two condition filter where name column could be used many times

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to return only the rows that match a two condition filter statement.
If I group_by names and the name is used in multiple rows I get every row with that name.

```
name <- c("Jeff", "Jeff", "Jeff", "Jeff", "Jill", "Jill", "Jill", "Jill", "Angie", "Angie", "Angie")

total <- c(123, 234, 432, 321,  345, 456, 654, 543, 567, 678, 789)

code <- c("abc", "xyz", "lmn", "opq", "abc", "xyz", "txy", "jkl",  "xyz", "tup", "rst")

table <- data.frame(name, total, code)
```

My table is:

```
name  total code
Jeff  123   abc
Jeff  234   xyz
Jeff  432   lmn
Jeff  321   opq
Jill  345   abc
Jill  456   xyz
Jill  654   txy
Jill  543   jkl
Angie 567   xyz
Angie 678   tup
Angie 789   rst
```

If I running this code:

```
library(dplyr)  
test1 <- table %>% group_by(name) %>% 
                   filter("abc" %in% code & "xyz" %in% code)
```

This gives me:

```
name  total code
Jeff  123   abc
Jeff  234   xyz
Jeff  432   lmn
Jeff  321   opq
Jill  345   abc
Jill  456   xyz
Jill  654   txy
Jill  543   jkl
```

I think that is issues is the group_by(name) but if I don't group_by(name) I cannot use the & statement on the same column for the filter.
I would like to output:

```
name  total code
Jeff  123   abc
Jeff  234   xyz
Jill  345   abc
Jill  456   xyz
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just expand the condition to specify that.

```
table %>% group_by(name) %>% 
  filter("abc" %in% code & "xyz" %in% code & (code == "abc" | code == "xyz"))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   name [2]
  name  total code 
  <fct> <dbl> <fct>
1 Jeff    123 abc  
2 Jeff    234 xyz  
3 Jill    345 abc  
4 Jill    456 xyz
```